# jQuery script conflicting in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Basically, I have two jQuery script on one page: jQuery.js and jquery-1.7.1.min.js.
one of it is for the popup window, the another is for the photo slider at the top of the page. However,
because there are the buttons under the photos to control the frame, when I click them in IE,it automatically takes you to another new window which is not correct...(it suppose to show another image in the slider in the same page)...

Here's my page: http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/spec/index.html?view=fps_trius_tour.html
Does anybody know how can I avoid the conflict and keep both popup window and slider in the same page?

Comment: Probably by using jQuery.noConflict() to create a separate jQuery reference for one of them.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm new in Javascript. I've tried to put jQuery.noConflict()  after import jQuery.js in html...but it block the function of jQuery.js.....